# How to access functions from traits?

Tags: scala, traits, function-calls

I am new to scala and was trying to use trait"s". My code looks something like this.

```
trait codeHelper {
  def functionCall(x: Integer){

     def valueChecker(){

     /*code to perform the required operation*/

     }
  }
}
```

I access the trait from my main scala class called "valueCreator" as follows:

```
 class valueCreator() extends baseClass() with codeHelper {
    val value = valueChecker() 
 }
```

However this code does not work. I get an error in my main class "valueCreator" saying

> "not found: value valueChecker"

Could somebody please tell me how could I access the function from the trait? Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: What is `checkLockInt`?

Comment: I am sorry. I corrected the error description now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `valueChecker` is inside another method, `functionCaller`, this is called a [*nested method*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/nested-functions.html). This means that the former method is function local and it is only available to `functionCaller`. If you want to make it visible at the `trait` level, you'll need to make it a separate method:

```
trait CodeHelper {
  def functionCall(x: Int) {
  }

  def valueChecker() {
     /*code to perform the required operation*/
  }
}
```

Although, it seems like you actually want to call `functionCaller` perhaps?

```
class ValueCreator extends BaseClass with CodeHelper {
    val value = functionCaller(2)
}
```

As a side note, class names in Scala are Pascal Case, meaning the first letter is upper case, not lower case.